# Hide a visual until slicers are selected in power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to display values on the table visual only when 3 of the slicers are selected or else no values should be displayed. For this, I did :

```
IF(ISFILTERED(Table[Country]),IF(ISFILTERED(Table[Procurement Team]),IF(ISFILTERED(Table[Class]),1,0),0),0)
```

Then in the Filters panel I put this measure and did `"is" 1.`
This means when the slicers are selected, i.e. TRUE then the values will be showed however this is working fine till procurement team selection but as soon as I am selecting class , the values in the table get populated. I am unable to understand why. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Are you using a table visual? What are the fields you put into the visual in addition to the measure?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using some of the fields inside the visual. Removing the filter context created by the visual might be a possible solution. To achieve this, use `ALLSELECTED`and `CALCULATE`

```
ToShow =
CALCULATE(
    IF(
        ISFILTERED( 'Table'[Country] ),
        IF(
            ISFILTERED( 'Table'[Procurement Team] ),
            IF( ISFILTERED( 'Table'[Class] ), 1, 0 ),
            0
        ),
        0
    ),
    ALLSELECTED( 'Table' )
)
```

and then you can implement your measures testing the [ToShow] like for instance

```
Sum Value =
IF( [ToShow] = 1, SUM( 'Table'[Value] ) )
```